# FaceAPI only give an exception

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I try to use the Azure Cognitve Services FaceAPI with the Adventure Works Sample from Microsoft.
Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/uwp-experiences/tree/AdventureWorks_v1_camera_app

Last week everything worked fine, but from today I only get the following exception:
Exception thrown: "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException" in Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.dll
Exception thrown: "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Comment: Could you give the full exception and stack trace? Have you tried drilling down into the exception using the debugger / locals window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that you exceeded your allowed number of calls, to increase the limitation you can buy the standard tier or if you're just testing then just wait for the Free tier to renew.